# Prove that for all integers $a$ and $b$ that $a + b$ and $a − b$ are either both odd or both even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove that for all integers $a$ and $b$ that $a + b$ and $a − b$ are either both odd or both even.

Stumped on this proof. I've only been able to figure it out assuming that both a and b are even:

$a = 2k$ and $b = 2n$

$2k + 2n = 2(k + n)$, definitely even. $2k - 2n = 2(k - n)$, also definitely even.

I don't think that this is the best way to go about proving this though.

Comment: $a+b+(a-b)=2a$ which is even, $a+b-(a-b)=2b$

Comment: I don't see how that helps me, could you explain more please?

Comment: So, $a+b=a-b+$ even, right? So, $a+b,a-b$ will have the same parity

Comment: You are doing good but you have to take all the different cases of 1. Odd and odd 2. Even and even 3. Odd and even. For odd take the number as 2n+1 and even as 2k where n and k is any integer

Comment: Consider the comment by lab bhattacharjee, it gives an elegant solution to your problem. But you can continue on the path you took. Just three more cases, all done much like you handled even-even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $a,b,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$
(a \mbox{ is even}) \land (b \mbox{ is even}) \implies \begin{cases} 
a=2p\\
b=2q
\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} 
a+b=2(p+q)&\mbox{(even)}\\
a-b=2(p-q)&\mbox{(even)}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
(a \mbox{ is even}) \land (b \mbox{ is odd}) \implies \begin{cases} 
a=2p\\
b=2q+1
\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} 
a+b=2(p+q)+1&\mbox{(odd)}\\
a-b=2(p-q)-1&\mbox{(odd)}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
(a \mbox{ is odd}) \land (b \mbox{ is even}) \implies \begin{cases} 
a=2p+1\\
b=2q
\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} 
a+b=2(p+q)+1&\mbox{(odd)}\\
a-b=2(p-q)+1&\mbox{(odd)}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
(a \mbox{ is odd}) \land (b \mbox{ is odd}) \implies \begin{cases} 
a=2p+1\\
b=2q+1
\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} 
a+b=2(p+q+1)&\mbox{(even)}\\
a-b=2(p-q)&\mbox{(even)}
\end{cases}
$$
or more elegantly:
$$
(a+b)-(a-b)=2b \iff (a+b)=(a-b) + 2b \implies (a+b)=(a-b) + \mbox{(even number)}
$$
so considering $a-b$ parity and using the above result:
$$
(a-b) \mbox{ is odd} \implies (a+b)=\mbox{(odd)} + \mbox{(even)}=\mbox{(odd number)}\\
(a-b) \mbox{ is even} \implies (a+b)=\mbox{(even)} + \mbox{(even)}=\mbox{(even number)}
$$

Comment: Ah, excellent! This is very clear to me now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Work with parity of $a$ and $b$ (i.e. mod 2). Take the 4 cases (Odd,odd), (odd, even) etc and conclude the result.

Answer (score 1):

Without having to look at cases:

Let $d=(a+b)-(a-b)$, think of it as the distance between $a+b$ and $a-b$.

Then, clearly, $d=2b$.   Since the distance between the two numbers is even, both numbers must have the same parity (either both even or both odd).

Answer (score 0):

**Case $1$:** $a$ is odd , $b$ is odd. Then $a=2m+ 1,b=2n+ 1$. So $a+b=2(m + n+1) $ $and $ $a-b=2(m-n-1),$ both of which are even. Similarly check for $a=2m-1$ and $b=2n-1$

**Case $2$:** $a$ is even , $b$ is odd. Then $a=2m,b=2n+ 1$. So $a+b=2(m + n)+1 $ $and $ $a-b=2(m-n)-1$ both of which are odd. Similarly check for $b=2n-1$

**Case $3$:** $a$ is odd , $b$ is even. Then $a=2m+1,b=2n$. So $a+b=2(m + n)+1 $ $and $ $a-b=2(m-n)+1$ both of which are odd. Similarly check for $a=2m-1$

**Case $4$:** $a$ is even , $b$ is even. Then $a=2m,b=2n$. So $a+b=2(m + n) $ $and $ $a-b=2(m-n)$ both of which are even. $\blacksquare$